# How to properly deserialize a top level generic with built_value

Tags: dart

I have a built_value object that's declared like so:

```
abstract class ParentItem<T> implements Built<ParentItem<T>, ParentItemBuilder<T>> {
  static Serializer<ParentItem> get serializer => _$parentItemSerializer;

  int get skip;
  int get limit;
  int get total;
  BuiltList<T> get items;

  ParentItem._();
  factory ParentItem([updates(ParentItemBuilder<T> b)]) = _$ParentItem<T>;
}
```

What is the proper way to deserialize this in dart / built_value? None of the following work:

```
// Fails with no builder for BuiltList<dynamic><Object>.
serializers.deserializeWith(ParentItem.serializer, json);
// Fails with _$ParentItemSerializer is not a subtype of Serializer<ParentItem<ConcreteType>>
serializers.deserializeWith<ParentItem<ConcreteType>>(ParentItem.serialize, json);
// Fails with no builder for ParentItem<dynamic><ConcreteType>
serializers.deserialize(json, new FullType(ParentItem, [new FullType(ConcreteType)]);
```

Comment: What does "None of the following work" mean exactly? Sounds similar to https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/404

Comment: Edited with actual errors returned

Comment: Do you have `@SerializersFor(const [
  ParentItem, ConcreteType})` in the file that contains `Serializers serializers = _$serializers = _$serializers.toBuilder()` ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes - but you have to explicitly tell the serializer about every possible generic version you want to include as well. I'll have an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Note that there are some cases where built_value *could* add the builder factories for you, but doesn't yet. There's an open issue for those cases

https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/124

but for top level generics there is no way for it to know--you'll have to add them yourself.

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example showing how to specify the exact types to the serializers ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the built_value generator creates specific versions of internally used generics for all possible concrete types, like so:

```
..addBuilderFactory(
  const FullType(ParentType, const [const FullType(ConcreteType)]),
  () => new ParentTypeBuilder<ConcreteType>())
```

But it does not do this (because how could it) for all combinations of a top level opject... so you have to add them yourself.

Comment: How exactly do you add the specific versions of the generics used ? Could you add a code sample please ?

Comment: Sure. The end_to_end_test for generics serialization has lots of examples

https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/end_to_end_test/test/generics_serializer_test.dart

I can't figure out how to format block code in a comment, or I'd copy one here. Look for "addBuilderFactory".

Comment: @Jeff can you share the changes you made. I think I made the change as per the test case, but I'm getting this error
````BuiltList<Object>' failed due to: Invalid argument(s): Unknown type on deserialization. Need either specifiedType or discriminator field.)````

Comment: I got the same error @Manish Ahuja , are you able to fix it?

Comment: For builtlist < mymodel > data, it cannot be serialized. If there is a minimum example, we would appreciate it